# HTML5 Maps for Windows Phone 8

Tags: html, google-maps, windows-phone, cross-platform

I'm building a cross-platform HTML5 app which needs to contain a map. Google Maps and Nokia Here Maps work well on all other platforms, but Windows Phone's browser behaves oddly. The map can be moved around, but I need another finger on the screen for the panning to work with another one.

Can anyone give me a proper solution what maps should I use or how do I make Google Maps or Nokia Here Maps work? The only feature I need from the maps is that I need to put pins on it that open an overlay box when clicked.

Comment: What example code have you tried from either Google Maps or Here Maps?

Comment: This for Nokia: http://developer.here.com/fi/javascript_api and GMaps.js (http://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/) for Google Maps.

Comment: Yeah...no one is gonna write this code for you. You need to provide the code you have already tried

Comment: I got Bing Maps Javascript API to work, so no problem here anymore.